# PostgreSQL update JSONB column with value from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I want to migrate data from one column (varchar) to another column (jsonb)

```
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('merchants_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying           | not null
 nameb      | jsonb                       | not null default '{}'::jsonb
```

So that `nameb` will became `{"en": "$name"}` where `$name` is a value in `name` field.

For example:

SELECT name, nameb

**before:**

```
                 name                 |   nameb    
--------------------------------------+------------
 hello                                | {} 
 world                                | {}
```

**after:**

```
                 name                 |   nameb    
--------------------------------------+------------
 hello                                | {"en": "hello"}
 world                                | {"en": "world"}
```

With regualar types I can do `UPDATE SET whatever = (SELECT ...)`, but How to do this with jsonb?

`UPDATE merchants SET nameb = (SELECT '{"en": "fillme!"}'::jsonb);` works, but how to set "fillme!" value from another field?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done with jsonb_build_object function which allows you to build json objects from simple data types.

So to do what you want:

```sql
update merchants set nameb = nameb || jsonb_build_object('en', name)
```

With json_build_object we are making {"en": "hello"}, {"en": "world"} ..dynamically based on value from "name" column.
After that we can simply concat to jsonb values with || operator.

This will not work if nameb is NULL because NULL will "eat" everything and result will be NULL again.
In that case I'd suggest to use COALESCE:

```sql
update merchants set nameb = COALESCE(nameb, '{}') || jsonb_build_object('en', name)
```

The other way to achieve the same is to use jsonb_set function. For this particluar case it's overkill, however it may be handy if you need to set some keys somewhere deeply in json:

```
update merchants set nameb = jsonb_set(nameb, '{en}', ('"' || name || '"')::jsonb)
```

This looks weird because we have to construct string surrounded of quotes , i.e: '"hello"' to set it as value for 'en' key. In case if you need to set some json, jsonb_build_object is more handy.

Answer (score 3):

I found solution:

```
UPDATE merchants AS m1 
SET nameb = (
  SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (
    SELECT name as en FROM merchants AS m2 WHERE m1.id = m2.id
  ) t
)::jsonb;
```

Not sure if it's right, but it works

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `jsonb_build_object` is best choice.

```
UPDATE merchants 
SET nameb = jsonb_build_object('en', "name", 
                               'cs', '')
WHERE ...
```

create

```
             name         |   nameb    
--------------------------+------------------------------
 hello                    | {"en": "hello", "cs": ""}
 world                    | {"en": "world", , "cs": ""}
```